# jquery draggable and resizable not working together in dynamically generated element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

New to programming so I'm still just figuring out how things work.  I'm trying to do the following:

- Create a new element
- Assign class ("docbox") and a dynamically generated id to the new element
- Make the element draggable and resizable
- Add it to the DOM

**Problem:**  Everything works except draggable() and resizable().  Draggable works until I try to add resizable.  I've tried changing how it's called and where it's called in the code, looked at a lot of SO questions, jQuery sources etc.  Not getting it.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
    var button = $("#documents_box");
    var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
    var counter = 0;

button.click(function () {
    var newCanvas = $('<canvas>');
    var boxNumber = counter; 
    counter++;
    newCanvas.draggable({containment: "parent"});
    //newCanvas.resizable({handles: "all"});
    newCanvas.addClass("docbox");
    newCanvas.attr("id", boxNumber);
    newCanvas.click(function () {
        var newClass = this.className;
        var newID = this.id;
            alert(newClass+newID);
    });

wrapper.append(newCanvas);
    });
```

});

And the Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4steqe2/18/

A mighty big thanks to anyone who can explain what I'm doing wrong.:p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `newCanvas.resizable` adds wrapping div around newCanvas node, so HTML will look like this:

```html
<div class="ui-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; ...">
    <canvas class="docbox ui-resizable" id="0" style="..."></canvas>
    <!-- UI HANDLES CODE -->
</div>
```

When you call `newCanvas.draggable({containment: "parent"});`
it will allow dragging `canvas` inside div added by resizable plugin.

It will work, after you change it to drag wrapping div, not canvas:

```
newCanvas.closest('div').draggable({containment: "parent"});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6pnuvg2k/1/

Comment: Thanks! That does it:).  I did see other references to needing a wrapping div but couldn't see how to make it work here. So the resizable plugin adds a div. and that's what you set draggable on.  No way could I get that from the jQuery docs.